# Hiding Undocumented Functions in a Package - Use of .function_name?

Tags: r, function

I've got some functions I need to make available in a package, and I don't want to export them or write documentation for them.  I'd just hide them inside another function but they need to be available to several functions so doing so becomes a scoping and maintenance issue.  What is the right way to do this?  By that I mean do they need special names, do they go somewhere other than the `R` subdirectory, can I put them in a single file, etc?  I've checked out the manuals, and what I'm after is like the `.internals` concept in the core, but I don't any instructions about how to do this generally.  I thought I had seen something about this before but cannot locate it just now.  Thx.

Comment: Writing R Extensions: Sect. 1.6.1 Specifying imports and exports.

Comment: @DWin That's a section I had gone to first, but it seems rather opaque.  For instance `The directive exportPattern("^[^\\.]") exports all variables that do not start with a period. ` implies that people might do this but doesn't say why or give any details or state that such variables (functions) might have special status.  Shortly after that, it says `Beware of patterns which include names starting with a period: some of these are internal-only variables and should never be exported, e.g. ‘.__S3MethodsTable__.’` but this seems to say don't step on core internal names.  And I'm not exporting.

Comment: Non-exportedness seems to be the default, and let's you not document that function or object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking on R-help, here is the answer.  @Dwin is correct, do not export the internal functions (so fix up your export instructions in NAMESPACE - don't use `exportPattern` but rather name the functions explicitly using `export`).  You can call them what you want, there is no special naming convention.  You do not have to write Rd files for them if you don't export them.

Comment: Technically, you don't have to write Rd files even if you do export them. :) It's just a good idea (of course), and repositories like CRAN will enforce documentation standards if you want to make your package publicly available.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to remove unnecessary function from NAMESPACE and call internal function by NAME-OF-PACKAGE:::NAME-OF-INTERNAL-FUNCTION. For example if your package name is RP and the name of the internal function is IFC. Then it would be like RP:::IFC(). Notice that if you use :: (two colon)then you can call functions that are listed in NAMESPACE and when you use :::  (three colon), you can call all functions including internal and exported functions.