# R function without exporting in Namespace

Tags: r, function, package

I am writing an R package. Generally, I have some functions that they are not useful for external uses. So when I put them in Namespace file, it causes an error about documentation of functions. On the other hand, if I remove them from Namespace file, it causes another problem, Function not found. So, is there any way of calling a function without a need of writing documentations?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  If you want to make the function available outside your package, you need to export the function, i.e. declare this in the NAMESPACE.  Writing documentation is a good thing.  Just do it - you'll be glad in the long term (i.e. next week when you can no longer remember what you did).

Comment: I found my answer: here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034309/hiding-undocumented-functions-in-a-package-use-of-function-name/25889422#25889422

Answer (score 0):

As Andrie commented if you want to include the function in the R package you need to put it inside a folder (e.g. packageparent/R/) and declare in NAMESPACE. You do not put a function in NAMESPACE.

IF you do not want to include it in your package, none of your functions in your package shall call this function, otherwise the package does not compile. You still can include this function in your package and not write any documentation for it.

To use this function outside your package just source it